# path of an image in an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, path, image

I'm trying to display two pictures on my JFrame, the way I found was to use icons and JLabels, this seems pretty straightforward and I'm not having problems with this. But when it comes to locating the image I can't get it to work. I'm on a linux machine thus the forwardslash style. I created a folder called pics in my project which is called 399assig1.

```
        ImageIcon icon1 = createImageIcon("/home/dsk03/ugrad/jeanbern/workspace/C291/workspace/399assig1/pics/fur-05.jpg","First");
    this.label1 = new JLabel("Picture 1", icon1, JLabel.CENTER);

    ImageIcon icon2 = createImageIcon("pics/fur.png","Second");
    this.label2 = new JLabel("Picture 2", icon2, JLabel.CENTER);
```

this is the error I get

```
Couldn't find file: /home/dsk03/ugrad/jeanbern/workspace/C291/workspace/399assig1/pics/fur-05.jpg
Couldn't find file: pics/fur.png
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: in Java you can always use forward slashes as path delimiters - even on a MS Windows environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if createImageIcon() is searching the CLASSPATH for the file, you'd need to add the root directory to the CLASSPATH.  A better approach would be use a path that is relative to a directory that is already included in the CLASSPATH.

Like so:

```
%>CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;/home/dsk03/ugrad/jeanbern/workspace
```

then your call would be

```
ImageIcon icon1 = createImageIcon("399assig1/pics/fur-05.jpg", "MyIcon");
```